# Deleting filtered files in Aix using Script

Tags: unix, aix

I need help in deleting files in one of my directories in Aix.

In deletion, manually, I am using the command:

to list the files:

```
find . -mtime +5 -type f
```

Then, if the listed files are good to be deleted, then I am going to use below:

to remove files:

```
find . -mtime +5 -type f -exec rm {} \;
```

My problem is, I am going to develop a scheduled job that would delete on my directory. BUT not all in my directory should be deleted. It is forbidden to delete the files that have extension of `.template`.

Example:

```
uafs9920.mailnote.template .
```

How can I automate this?

Answer (score 2):

Use **`-not`**, combined with **`-name`**.

```
find . -type f -mtime +5 -not -name "*.template" -exec rm {} \;
```

Or:

```
find . -type f -mtime +5 -not -name "*.template" -delete
```

Comment: Wow! I will try this. Thank you so much for the response, Grawity. :)

Comment: Hi, I tried the command but I received below error:

find: 0652-017 -not is not a valid option.

Answer (score 0):

Upon browsing here in superuser, I looked for other asked questions that are somehow related or connected to my question. And in one of the topics, I saw the command:

find . -type f ! -name '*.template*' -mtime +5 -exec rm {} \;

I tried it on my Unix Env and it works. :)